# DIV absolute respeitar padding da DIV pai

Tags: html, css

Preciso colocar uma `div` com a propriedade `position` = `absolute`. Porém, a `div` pai tem um `padding` e o `width: 100%` da `div` filho não respeita esse `padding`.

Será que a única saída seria definir o `width` com o `javascript`?

[image]

Coloquei um exemplo aqui:

```css
.master {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="child">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi se você quer respeitar o padding e reduzir a largura do amarelo, ou se apenas resposicionar o amarelo. Posicionamento absoluto não respeita padding dos ancestrais.

Comment: Eu quero respeitar o padding

Comment: O `padding` altera o tamanho do elemento, então é esperado que o elemento filho, configurado com `width: 100%`, fique também com 220px de largura. Tire o `position: absolute`, como o @bfavaretto disse e terá um elemento com 200px.

Comment: Se você quer que um div ocupe todo o espaço de largura do pai, respeitando os paddings, por que então usar `position: absolute`? Usar o div no seu padrão já faz isso. Só tirar as propriedades `width` e `position` dali.

Comment: Ali só foi um exemplo, preciso do `position: absolute` porque essa `div` amarela vai ficar flutuando por cima do conteúdo restante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, é isso que você quer.

```css
*,*:before,*:after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pai{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.filho{
width: calc(100% - 10px);
height: 50px;
background: red;
position: absolute;
left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
        <div class="filho">
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Na verdade é quase isso, mas o `width` da `div` filho teria que ter o 100% da `div` pai menos o `padding` da `div` pai.

Comment: @RobertoFagundes Atualizei

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou da forma que eu esperava

Comment: Vale lembrar que `calc` é uma tecnologia em experiência e deve ser utilizada com muita cautela. É possível que alguns navegadores não suportem ou que tenha um comportamento diferente do esperado.

Comment: Na verdade, `calc(100% - 20px);`, pois tem padding dos dois lados, e retirar o `left` do filho.

Comment: @Dudaskank Sim, ali foi só um exemplo